# maven servlet HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jakarta-ee, servlets

Cant run maven servlet whatever i do. If i restart server, ill get next error:

```
     HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet ---
```

If i restart page without restarting a server - ill get

```
     HTTP Status 404 -
```

There is maven project structure.

[image]
web.xml:

```
     <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

     <web-app>
       <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Cezar</servlet-name>
          <display-name>Cezar</display-name>
          <description></description>
          <servlet-class>Cezar</servlet-class>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Cezar</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/Cezar</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
     </web-app>
```

Cezar.java:

```
      import java.io.IOException;
      import javax.servlet.ServletException;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

      public class Cezar extends HttpServlet {
          public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse                   response)
        throws IOException{
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>"); 
        }
   }
```

deployment assembly:

[image]

Comment: plz share ur Deployment Assembly details.Right Click on ur web project in Project Explorer -> select 'Properties'. Under project properties, select 'Deployment Assembly'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application has a structural error.

The source file Cezar.java should be in `src/main/java` instead of `src/main/resources`.

Therefore the file is not being compiled into the `Cezar.class` file which would be added to your web application's `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Comment: Yea this was the fix for me. Odd enough that the maven webapp project doesn't come with a java folder so I had to add it myself. Great job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes he is true and better to maintain package structure and give the fully qualified name in web.xml at  Example: your package name.your servlet class name.